# error: initializations for multiple members

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, unions, bit-fields

I'm trying to create a constexpr union that sets the last 3 bits of its value according to template parameters. The idea is that the constructor first initializes the `val` variable to whatever is passed to the constructor and then the last three bits are set with template parameters and a bitfield. However, the compiler is complaining.

**My code**:

```
template<typename T, bool a, bool b, bool c>
union some_type
{
    T val;
    struct {
        T empty_ : sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-3;
        T a_ : 1;
        T b_ : 1;
        T c_ : 1;
    } bit_type;

    some_type(uint32_t var) : val{var}, bit_type{0,a,b,c} {}
};


int main()
{
    some_type<uint32_t,1,1,0>(245878);
}
```

**Error**:

```
<source>:244:37:   required from here
<source>:234:5: error: initializations for multiple members of 'some_type<unsigned int, true, true, false>'
  234 |     some_type(uint32_t var) : type{var}, bit_type{0,a,b,c} {}
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
```

Is there someway I can set the last three bits of a value in a constexpr way AND perserve the information of which bits were stored (in the above example by naming the bits a_, b_, c_ for later read operations)?

Comment: You cannot modify the value of `val` through `bit_type`. Only one of the members is active at a time. Why do you not simply use common bit manipulation through `&`, `|`, `<<` etc.?

Comment: @user17732522: Exactly. I'm doing it this way because I want to reference some_type.bit_type.a_ later on for reading. This way reading and writing stays consistent over the course of the program and is neatly packed up inside a struct. But if I understand correctly it is not possible

Comment: No it is not possible.  You can instead write functions retrieving and setting the bits via the bit manipulation. Users can then call these functions instead of referencing the bitfield.